# My variable in callback is throwing its value times 10

Tags: javascript

I created a shuffle with no duplicates where I can input the max value.

However when I input "6" the value from the shuffle goes up to 60, this is not intended.

Just before appending the random value I added an alert for the var "max" value, and it displays 6, so I can't figure out where the 60 is coming from, 1 becomes 10, 2 becomes 20 and so on.

Here is the code:

JS:

```
var skip = new Array;
var max = 100;
var go;
var myFunction = function() {
max = $("#max").val();

go();
return max;
};



$(document).ready(function () {

    function randGen(max) {
    do { var myNum = Math.floor( (Math.random() * (max + 1)) ); } while (skip.indexOf(myNum) != -1)
    skip.push(myNum);
    return myNum;
}

btn = document.getElementById('max')
btn.addEventListener('change', myFunction)    

go = function() {   
var skip = new Array;

$('.generate').html( max );

  };
  $('.generate').on('click', function() {

var gen = $('.generate').html( randGen( max ) );

    $('p').append( gen + ", ");
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">





<link href="css/odometer-theme-default.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />

<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  </head>
  <body>




<div class="center"><button id="belly" class="generate number odometer">0</button></div>

<form class="options"> 
<div class="credit">How many words?</div>
</br>
  <label for="max">Max</label>
  <input type="number" id="max" name="max" autofocus>

</form> 
<p></p>
<img src="imgs/iedis.png" id="logo" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:max;height:max;">
<script>
if('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
           .register('/sw.js')
           .then(function() { console.log("Service Worker Registered"); });
}
</script>
  </body>


<script src="scripts/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/odometer.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/funciones.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Try and keep your question code as simple and focused as possible, the most minimal thing that reproduces your problem. This has a ton of seemingly irrelevant code in it. Also why `new Array` instead of `[ ]`? This code is a mess of styles, the indentation is a wreck, and it's really hard to read.

Comment: `max = $("#max").val();` => `max = Number($("#max").val());`

Comment: @JaromandaX Ah, it's being interpreted as `'6' + 1` which is, of course, 61.

Comment: @JaromandaX you have answered my question, would you post as answer so I can mark it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`max = $("#max").val();` is a string

if you enter `6`

`Math.random() * (max + 1)` becomes `Math.random() * ("61")`

The `*` coerces the string `"61"` to a Number - therefore your essentially doing `Math.random() * (Number(max) * 10 + 1)`

Simple fix is to parse the string as a Number

```
max = Number($("#max").val())
```

or

```
max = parseInt($("#max").val())
```

or

```
max = parseFloat($("#max").val())
```

or

```
max = 1 * $("#max").val();
```

or even

```
max = $("#max").val() - 0;
```

There's probably a few more ways to do it